# Maya Python : Im listing relatives of a group but when i go to select the relatives it says none

Tags: python, select, maya, mel

Hi so Im trying to list all the relatives of this group in Maya. it returns the list fine, but when i go to select everything in the list, it prints out that none is selected?

```
mySel = cmds.ls(selection=True)
print(mySel)

rel = cmds.listRelatives(ad=True , pa=True)
print(mySel)

cmds.rename(mySel + '_grp')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @sophie-ridley, your code works for me, but you need to change `cmds.rename(mySel + '_grp')`. `cmds.rename()` takes two string parameters, the old name, and the new name, maybe you want `cmds.rename(mySel, 'mySel_grp')`? See the example at the bottom of the docs https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/CommandsPython/rename.html shows `cmds.rename( 'nsA:sphere3', 'sphere4' )`, try to use that syntax and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Right now when you use `cmds.ls(selection=True)` to capture the selection it will return you a list of strings.

The rename method expects 2 `strings` as parameters, an existing object to rename, and what to rename it to.

So what you're doing now is passing `mySel`, a whole list of strings, when it only accepts one. If you want to rename multiple objects at once then you need to use a `for` loop to operate on them one by one:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

mySel = cmds.ls(selection=True) # Get a list of the current selection.

for i, obj in enumerate(mySel): # Loop over selection, one by one.
    newName = "{}_{}_grp".format(obj, i) # Build the new name.
    cmds.rename(obj, newName) # Finally rename the object.
```

Also with `cmds.listRelatives` it's possible that it will return `None` if the object has no shapes/children, or you simply have nothing selected. So you may need an `if` condition to make sure it returns something.

Hope that makes it more clear.